# How to check password strength in popup using angular 4

Tags: angular

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcJ9T.png)

Need to show the popup to show the password validation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking like this i think you should be following this link
it might work for you

[Check password Strength](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-check-password-strength-meter-in-angular-8/)